# IBM MQ PCF command to collect QAlias details like Target base object name

Tags: ibm-mq, pcf

I was looking to see if there are ways to collect MQ object details other than names using PCF commands. For E.g. If I would like see where a QAlias is pointing to or the Target base object, how do I generate a PCF command to accomplish this??

Comment: Are you doing this in Java ? Or... ?

Comment: Yes I am doing in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the information in the link that Morag gave you and then you need to do something like:

```
agent = new PCFMessageAgent(qMgrName);
request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_ALIAS);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_Q_ATTRS,
                     new int [] { MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, MQConstants.MQCA_BASE_NAME });
responses = agent.send (request);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing something like this                                                                    PCFParameter [] parameters = 
  {
  new MQCFST (CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME,"*"),
  new MQCFIN (CMQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, CMQC.MQQT_ALIAS),
  new MQCFIN(CMQCFC.MQIACF_Q_ATTRS,CMQC.MQCA_BASE_OBJECT_NAME)};                                                                                                            It did not work!

Comment: One more question? How do I process the PCF response. I am getting 3020 error when I do below.                                                                           String[] qanames = (String[])responses[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCACF_Q_NAMES);

Comment: MQCACF_Q_NAMES won't be returned in a MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q command, only in an MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES. To get the queue attributes back and not just the list names you should be using MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q. See knowledge center for all the parameters that are returned and only do getParameterValue on ones that are actually there.

Answer (score 2):

There are PCF commands that are equivalents of all the MQSC commands. So if you can do it with MQSC you can also achieve the same thing with PCF.

The MQSC command `DISPLAY QALIAS(q-name) ALL` can be done in PCF using the Inquire Queue command - that is `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q` and providing the name of the queue you want to know about in the Queue Name `MQCA_Q_NAME` parameter. You can see all the returned parameters in the Knowledge Center.

**Reference**

- [Inquire Queue PCF Command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087800_.htm)