# Getting the list of all the Queues under a Queue Manager?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am working on a utility to browse/read all the messages from each of the queues in a Queue Manager. I am successful in creating a rest web service which can read the specified number of messages from the specified Queue.I am using MQ APIs in my classes to establish the connections.

```
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;
```

My url looks like :

http://localhost:8090/queueManager/{queueManagerName}/queue/{queueName}?msgsToRead=-1&&saveMsgs=false

Now I want to create something which doesn't need to specify the queue name instead just take the Queue Manager name and read all the messages from each queue.

I want to a url like this :
http://localhost:8090/queueManager/{queueManagerName}

Can someone guide me to list all the Queues of a QueueManager using MQ API Classes.

Comment: You need to use the MQ PCF classes to get a list of queues.

Comment: @roger I tried finding examples of it, can you point me to an example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232494/ibm-mq-pcf-command-to-collect-qalias-details-like-target-base-object-name